# Remove and update groups on redraw with D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

`visibleData` is updated when resizing or moving a brush.

I want to remove the groups (rectangle+text) that are no longer in `visibleData` and update the rectangles positions and dimensions from the groups that are still part of `visibleData`:

**First variant of the redraw function:**

```
var grp = items.selectAll('g')
        .data(visibleData);

var item = grp.enter().append('g')
        .attr('transform', function (d) {
            return 'translate(' + d.x + ', ' + d.y + ')';
        });

item.append('rect')
        .attr('width', rectWidth)
        .attr('height', rectHeight)
        .style('fill', 'gray');

item.append('text')
        .text(function (d) {
            return d.id;
        })
        .attr('x', 10)
        .attr('y', 15);

grp.exit().remove();
```

**Second variant:**

```
var grp = items.selectAll('g')
        .data(visibleData);

var item = grp.enter().append('g');

item.append('rect')
        .attr('x', function (d) {
            return d.x
        })
        .attr('y', function (d) {
            return d.y;
        })
        .attr('width', rectWidth)
        .attr('height', rectHeight)
        .style('fill', 'gray');

item.append('text')
        .text(function (d) {
            return d.id;
        })
        .attr('x', function (d) {
            return d.x + 5
        })
        .attr('y', function (d) {
            return d.y + 15;
        });

grp.exit().remove();
```

Here is the full code for the first variant : http://jsfiddle.net/vvorm/F62kt/1/

As you can see, neither of them work properly when resizing the brush *from the left*. I haven't managed to update the rectangles' positions and dimensions but I think it's more important to handle the removal first.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Solved my problem using the identity function:

```
.data(vm.visibleData, function (d) {
    return vm.visibleData.indexOf(d);
})
```

Thanks to http://orangevolt.blogspot.fr/2013/04/update-d3js-data-using-enterexit-with.html